# Printing values of PriorityQueue using Streams gives incorrect result

Tags: java

PriorityQueue in Java always stores elements in the ascending order if no comparator is specified during its declaration. This is easily provable by the following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(); 
    // as no custom comparator is provided, it stores the element in ascending order

    pq.add(1);
    pq.add(3);
    pq.add(0);
    pq.add(100);
    pq.add(50);
    while (pq.peek() != null) {
        System.out.println(pq.poll());
    }

}
```

This results in output of

```
0
1
3
50
100
```

Now, if I use Java8 to print the elements of the priorityQueue before I apply the `peek` method, ideally I should get an output similar to the above one where elements are printed in their increasing order.

```
    pq.forEach(System.out::println);
```

However, the following piece of code prints the elements in some random order i.e neither in the insertion order nor in ascending order. It gives an output as

```
0
3
1
100
50
```

My question is that why does priority queue behave differently when we peek the elements and differently when we just print the elements. Is there some underlying concept that I am missing here ? TIA

Comment: From the Javadoc: "The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order."

Comment: `poll()` modifies the priority queue and "finishes the sorting."